# Tweepy can't get video clip info from Tweets

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./tweets_fetch.py", line
>   22, in 
>       for media in i.extended_entities['media']['video_info']: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

How exactly can I extract video mp4 file link from User123 tweets?

```
tweets_message = api.user_timeline(screen_name = 'User123', count = 1, include_rts = True)
for i in tweets_message:
        for media in i.extended_entities['media']['video_info']:
                print (media)
```

expecting to a list of mp4 files at different bitrates

Comment: Are you using tweet_mode=extended when you retrieve the Tweets?

Comment: File "./tweets_fetch.py", line 22, in <module>
    for media in i.extended_entities['media']['video_info']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: that's the result after using extended mode

Comment: is there a specific Tweet ID that this is failing on?

Comment: I think there needs to be a number between ['media'] and ['video_info'] as there can be more than one, so you could try `i.extended_entities['media'][0]['video_info']` of course that's no good if you have more than one, but give it a try (might need to move your code round a bit) and see what you get. (Try combining with Andy's answer also).